# how can I match only the word and make them string within the string with tag-set?

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file whose strings are like this.

```
The/at Fulton/np-tl County/nn-tl Grand/jj-tl Jury/nn-tl said/vbd Friday/nr an/at investigation/nn of/in Atlanta's/np$ recent/jj primary/nn election/nn produced/vbd ``/`` no/at evidence/nn ''/'' that/cs any/dti irregularities/nns took/vbd place/nn ./.
```

here, after "/" is the tag of previous word. what I want is just that word, not including tag set. I tried following code.

```
import re
f = open(textfile)
raw = f.read()
match = re.findall(r'\w+(?=/)', raw)
print match
```

it returns me the list of words without "/" but problem occur.
first I want the data of string, not the list of words.
second, for example, in "Atlanta's/np$" , it gives me just "s", not 
"Atlanta's"....

is there any efficient way to remove tag set and return me only the raw string?

Comment: for first part of your question, you can write a for loop: `string = "" for m in match: string += m + " "`

Comment: Your question is unclear: what do you want to do with slashes surrounded with two backticks and two single quotes? Other thing, for what reason do you use `re.findall` since your goal is to obtain a string from a string? Why not a replacement approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution:

1. Change your regex from '\w+(?=/)' to '\b\S+(?=/)'
2. Concatenate your results as follows:

(Create an empty string and loop through matches concatenating with a space.)

```
result = ""

for m in match:

    result = result + " " + m
```

See the following Python Fiddle.
http://pythonfiddle.com/regex-example